# How to play RealMedia videos embedded within Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video-player

I've installed Real Player from Medibuntu (64 bits version).
It works well to read downloaded Real Media Videos but not for embedded RM Videos.

I've the "Helix DNA Plugin: RealPlayer G2 Plug-In Compatible" within the Firefox about:plugins but embedded videos don't work. Those videos are using this html code :

```
<object classid="CLSID:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11CF-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA">
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Install Xine and Xine plugin. This plug-in can play real videos.